How to reduce memory usage of measure?
I have a table in PowerBI in which I have the stock quantities for different products and multiple stores across different months. I also have a calendar table and a store mapping table. In a sheet I inserted two slicers, one for the date and one for the stores. The date is from the calendar table and the store name from the store mapping table. Both have single selection active (only one store and one date can be selected). In a table visual I want to show each of the product ids a store has in stock for a given month. I created a measure to show in how many other stores does a certain product id appear with a stock greater than 0. The measure works fine for a smaller database:
Total Stores per product =
VAR YEAR = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[YEAR])
VAR MONTH = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Month])
VAR MONTH_no = MONTH(DATEVALUE(MONTH & " 1, " & AN))
VAR date = EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR, MONTH_no, 1), 0)
VAR product_id = SELECTEDVALUE('PRODUCTS'[NUM_ART])
RETURN
CALCULATE
(
    COUNTROWS('PRODUCTS'),
    FILTER(
        ALL('PRODUCTS'),
        'PRODUCTS'[stock_quantity] > 0 && 'PRODUCTS'[data_stock] = date && 'PRODUCTS'[NUM_ART] = product_id
    )
)

The problem I am facing is that I have a large dataset and when trying to insert this measure in a table visual it crashes, meaning it exceeds the available resources.
I am asking for your help to somehow rewrite the measure so the computing resources are decreased. I know the COUNTROWS and FILTER functions take up a lot of memory usage but I am not sure how should I modify the measure so the final result to be the same.

Do you prefer to view a table displaying the list of unique Product IDs with available stock for a specific date and store, or do you simply need the total count of these unique Product IDs for the same parameters?
If first, you could just drag the ProductId (from the fact table or product dim table) into the table visual, and place a filter on that table to remove all products with no stock quantity (either by the column or by a measure). Because you are already manipulating the filter context with the Date and Store slicer, you do not need to store these values elsewhere.
Before filter: image
After filter: image
If second, you could create a measure like this:
CurrentStockQuantity = MAX(stock_quantities[StockQuantity]) 

TotalProductsInStock = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(stock_quantities[ProductId]),
        FILTER(
            stock_quantities,
            [CurrentStockQuantity] > 0
        )
    )


You are already filtering the whole data model by StoreId and Date. This means you can just count the remaining unique products.
The additional filter is added to exclude any products that have no stock quantity available.

Your current measure basically iterates over the whole products table again, removing all filters that ever have been applied to them. It's basically just a full scan, row-by-row.

Thank you for your answer! What I need to do is the following:

first I need to show all product ids in a table visual by simply dragging the product id column into a table visual
-second, I need to create a measure which shows in how many stores does a specific product id appear with a stock greater than 0
I believe your approach does not take into account the slicers present on the page and it will return only 1, given a certain store will be selected from the slicer (in that store that product id will have a stock greater than 0)


Could you perhaps update your original post with an example of how it should look like? That would make it easier. Perhaps give some sample data so we can figure a solution.
